# show/hide using jquery

Tags: jquery, hide, show

I have trouble hiding and showing the p tag. Could someone help me with this code. What I am 
trying to accomplish is that when you click the hide button, the content is hidden. Then when you are ready to show the content you click the show button. I know you can uses the toggle but i dont want to do that

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(value){
  $("button").click(function(value){
    if (value==="hide"){
        $("p").hide();}
    else 
          $("p").show();
  });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h2>This is a heading</h2>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<button value="hide">Hide me</button>
<button value="show">Show me</button>
</body>
</html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(value){
  $("button").click(function(value){
    if (value==="hide"){
        $("p").hide();}
    else 
          $("p").show();
  });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h2>This is a heading</h2>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<button value="hide">Hide me</button>
<button value="show">Show me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't have multiple `id` s with the same name. Use `class` es instead.

Comment: @patrick - non-unique IDs IS invalid HTML markup.

Comment: @Charles - Yes, a distinction was implied that I did not intend. I ought to have stated the invalid markup in addition to that which karim79 had already pointed out. Namely closing HTML tags with `}` instead of `>`.

Comment: @patrick - I figured that - I just wanted to make sure that was pointed out because the asker is clearly a beginner and wanted to make sure he understood why non-unique IDs aren't allowed.

Comment: @Charles - Good call. It was sloppy on my part. Certainly worth pointing out.

Comment: I changed the ids  to classes slick-box1 and slickbox2 as suggested but nothing happening. Its not firing at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Currently it doesn't work with multiple
>   content.

That is because you have duplicate IDs on your page. To fix that, use classes, and target the next .slickbox div from the clicked anchor:

```
$('a.slick-toggle').click(function() { 
    $(this).next("div").find(".slickbox").toggle(400);
    return false;
});
```

..and change the IDs to classes, e.g.:

```
<a class="slick-toggle" href="#">Toggle the box</a>
<div style="position:relative; outline: 1px dashed orange; padding:100px;">
    <div class="slickbox" style=" outline: 1px dashed hotpink; background-color:#ccc;position:absolute; top:100px; left: 20px;">
        <h2> music nsme</h2>
        <p>This is the box that will be shown and hidden and togg </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A little hard to tell with the condition of the markup, but I think each `slickbox` is a child of the next `div` sibling to each `slick-toggle`.

Comment: @patrick dw - I think you're right. I updated my answer to reflect. Thank you :)

Comment: karim79: You're welcome, although the HTML you provided didn't reflect your correct js code solution. Hope you don't mind that I updated it.

Comment: @patrick dw - not at all. The markup I provided was intended only to show that the relevant parts (the anchors and divs) should use classes as opposed to IDs, but in retrospect, it might have been confusing. Thanks again!

Comment: @karim79 - Speaking of that, I guess I copied over the HTML without changing the ids to classes. Fixed. Looks like OP changed the code in the question to use `slickbox1`, `slickbox2`, etc.. I think I'll roll back the question so your answer makes sense.

Comment: @patrick dw - Wooh! This is sorted now. Thanks for your attention. I sometimes think I need help - I'm on holiday until the beginning of 2011 and so far all I've done is answer stuff on this godforsaken website.

Comment: @karim79: Well, it's not called CrackOverflow for nothing. :o)

Comment: @patrick dw - Hahaaa! I haven't heard that one before! Now I am deeply disturbed!